# Autofill column of a DataFrame with random strings until the column is depleted

Tags: python, random, dataframe, series

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

staff = ['Emelia','Raphael','Mike', 'Peter']

staff_l = []
for i in random.choice(staff, 4):
    staff_l.append(i)
s = Series(staff_l,index=['A','B','C','D'])

dframe = DataFrame(index=['A','B','C','D','E','F'],columns=['Morning','Afternoon'])

dframe.fillna(s)
```

I want to be able to fill the 'Morning' column with random choice of the names of staff until the column ends and fill the afternoon column also. Since I cant use a list I converted it into a series and still not working. When I use this code dframe.fillna(s) it gives me a NaN column. I cant seem to replace the NaN.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to be at least clear about the size of the the dataframe.

In your case

this one works

```
import pandas as pd
import random 
staff = ['Emelia','Raphael','Mike', 'Peter']
yourframe=pd.Dataframe(index=['A','B','C','D','E','F'],columns=['Morning','Afternoon'])
for x in yourframe.index.values:
    yourframe.set_value(x,'Morning',random.choice(staff))

for x in yourframe.index.values:
    yourframe.set_value(x,'Afternoon',random.choice(staff))
```

You can put them in the same loop since random.choice returns random values but i am not sure what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

[`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) returns another dataframe.  It does not actually modify `dframe` unless you add the `inplace` argument.

```
dframe.fillna(s, inplace=True)
```

Or alternatively, you can reassign `dframe`

```
dframe = dframe.fillna(s)
```

Whether or not you want to use `inplace` is up to you, but here is a decent discussion on the pros/cons of using it: [guidelines on using pandas inplace keyword argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34320137/guidelines-on-using-pandas-inplace-keyword-argument)