# how to replace multiple values with one value python

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, replace

How can I replace the data `'Beer','Alcohol','Beverage','Drink'` with only `'Drink'`.

```py
df.replace(['Beer','Alcohol','Beverage','Drink'],'Drink')
```

doesn't work

Comment: If your question was answered, please reward the efforts of those who helped you. Accept the most helpful answer. You can also upvote all other useful answers. Please make it a habit, it helps the community.

Comment: This code does work in pandas now, see example 3 on https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Answer (score 27):

You *almost* had it. You need to pass a dictionary to `df.replace`.

```
df

       Col1
0      Beer
1   Alcohol
2  Beverage
3     Drink
```

```
df.replace(dict.fromkeys(['Beer','Alcohol','Beverage','Drink'], 'Drink'))

    Col1
0  Drink
1  Drink
2  Drink
3  Drink
```

This works for exact matches and replacements. For partial matches and substring matching, use

```
df.replace(
    dict.fromkeys(['Beer','Alcohol','Beverage','Drink'], 'Drink'), 
    regex=True
)
```

This is not an in-place operation so don't forget to assign the result back.

Comment: Ha!  I was going to `df.replace({k: 'Drink' for k in ['Beer','Alcohol','Beverage','Drink']})`  But instead, I learned about `dict.fromkeys`

Comment: Won't passing `inplace=True` to df.replace make it an in-place operations, if desired?

Comment: @2Toad it would but I don't recommend it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020384/4909087

Answer (score 6):

Try the following approach:

```
lst = ['Beer','Alcohol','Beverage','Drink']
pat = r"\b(?:{})\b".format('|'.join(lst))

df = df.replace(pat, 'Drink', regexp=True)
```

Comment: Nice one , just do not know why yours and mine are different but can get the same result ...Sorry I am not quit work with strings...can you refer some link for future studying

Answer (score 4):

Looks like different from MaxU's solution :)

```
df.replace({'|'.join(['Beer','Alcohol','Beverage','Drink']):'Drink'},regex=True)
```

Comment: which python version is it ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your initial method of doing it works in the the latest iteration of Python.

```
df.replace(['Beer','Alcohol','Beverage','Drink'],'Drink', inplace=True)
```

Should work

Answer (score 2):

Slight change in earlier answers:
Following code Replacing values of specific column/Columns

```python
df[['Col1']] = df[['Col1']].replace(dict.fromkeys(['Beer','Alcohol','Beverage','Drink'], 'Drink'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not relevant to your exact case using strings, but relevant to the question as stated in the title:

If you have a range of numbers you would like to replace you can provide `range()` as a dict key.

```py
# Dymmy dataframe with two columns
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], b=[66, 44, 33, 22, 77]))

# Mapping that will replace 1 with 'x', 2, 3, 4 with 'y' and 5 with 'z' in column 'a'
mapping = {"a": {1: "x", range(2, 5): "y", 5: "z"}}
df.replace(mapping)
```