# Check if multiple values exists in df

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

```
list_columns = ['weight', 'animal', 'age']
list_data = [
    [14, '2. D', 10],
    [4, 'DOG2-', 2],
    [7, 'DOG1-', 3],
    [6, 'DOG1', 5]
    ]
df_animals = pd.DataFrame(columns=list_columns, data=list_data)
df_animals.head()
```

I want to check if the following values `'2. D','DOG2-','DOG1-','dddog'` exists in my df, and if so, to repalce them with the string `'dog1'`

**My tries:**

For just one value I can do this:

```
if 'DOG2-' in df_animals.values:
    df_animals['animal'] = df_animals['animal'].replace({'DOG2-':'dog1'})
```

I tought using a list but doesen't work because of the signs `- .`. Witought them it does the job.

```
list = ('2. D','DOG2-','DOG1-','DOG-')
if list in df_animals.values:
    df_animals['animal'] = df_animals['animal'].replace({'2. D':'DOG2','DOG2-':'DOG2','DOG1-':'DOG1','DOGG 1':'DOG1'})
```

This just returns the same df with the warning: `FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison`

I am now thinking to use `python’s RegEx (re) library` but it would be to many lines and don't know if it's the most pythonic way. With the list seems simple but I think I am missing somethig. Could someone help me with an idea about my issue?

Comment: `df.replace(('2. D','DOG2-','DOG1-','DOG-'), 'blah')` you can replace multiple values.

Comment: I was sure it had to be something simple. Thank you @cs95 . Please post this as a question. I will accept the answer and maybe could also help others.

Comment: Thanks but this is a duplicate question. You can vote on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46920621/4909087) to the duplicate target if you wish. Thanks :-)