# When do need to specify the inplace aargument in a Pandas dataframe operation

Tags: pandas

In a pandas dataframe, when I want to change the original dataframe, i.e by changing formatting of columns, adding/dropping columns, use substring on a column, I am not sure when I need to use `inplace=True` and when I don't need this argument?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570984/pandas-is-inplace-true-considered-harmful-or-not

Comment: @coldspeed Consider changing your name to `lightspeed`

Comment: You don't need inplace=True... you rarely ever will. It was a mistake adding it into the API.