# How to store a new dataframe after using a self defined function on it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, user-defined-functions

I am just starting to use user-defined functions, so this is probably not a very complex question, forgive me.

I have a few dataframes, which all have a column named 'interval_time' (for example) and I would like to rename this column 'Timestamp'.

I know that I can do this manually with this;

```
df = df.rename(index=str, columns={'interval_time': 'Timestamp'})
```

but now I would like to define a function called rename that does this for me. I have seen that this works;

```
def rename(data):
    print(data.rename(index=str, columns={'interval_time': 'Timestamp'}))
```

but I can't seem to figure out to save the renamed dataframe, I have tried this;

```
def rename(data):
    data = data.rename(index=str, columns={'interval_time': 'Timestamp'})
```

The dataframes that I am using have the following form;

```
df_scada
              interval_time                 A         ...             X                 Y 
0       2010-11-01 00:00:00                0.0        ...                396.36710         381.68860
1       2010-11-01 00:05:00                0.0        ...                392.97974         381.40634
2       2010-11-01 00:10:00                0.0        ...                390.15695         379.99493
3       2010-11-01 00:15:00                0.0        ...                389.02786         379.14810
```

Comment: let me know if I need to include anything else for the MCVE

Comment: What about `return data.rename(...)` inside `rename` function and then `df = rename(df)`?

Comment: beautiful, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few points to note:

- You need to use `return` in your function.
- It's good practice to make such functions generic. For example, your input and output column names can be arguments with default values set.
- Pandas offers [`pd.DataFrame.pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) to facilitate method chaining.
- You should not name your function the same as the Pandas method. This will only lead to confusion.

Putting these elements together:

```
def rename_col(data, col_in='interval_time', col_out='Timestamp'):
    return data.rename(index=str, columns={col_in: col_out})

df = df.pipe(rename_col)
```

This is a trivial example, which probably doesn't *require* a user-defined function. However, the above advice may help when you write more complex functions.

Comment: I agree that this is quite trivial, I could have done it more simply another way, I am just starting to understand how to use user-defined functions, so thought this was a good thing to try

Comment: @LukaVlaskalic, No problem, I thought so, which is why I thought I'd give some extra pointers :)

Comment: I just updated the question with a further complexity

Comment: I've rolled back. Please ask as a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Since there are already 3 answers, it's not practical for everyone to update their answers with the new requirement.

Comment: So if you really want to improve on pandas, check the brilliant [Modern Pandas](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-1-intro.html) blog series.

Comment: I didn't realise that everyone would need to change their answers, I just wanted a little bit of further help, and unfortunately, I can only post a question every 90 mins. But no worries, I now managed to post the question, thank you

Comment: @LukaVlaskalic, Yep, unfortunately that's how SO work. Many people view all the answers (each may have a different valid solution), so having incomplete ones spoils the party.

Comment: I gathered as much, for sure makes sense

Answer (score 2):

Without inplace=True, the function creates a new object, which needs to be returned:

```
import pandas as pd

def rename(data):
    return data.rename(index=str, columns={'interval_time': 'Timestamp'})

data = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4], columns=['interval_time'])
renamed_data = rename(data)
```

If no new DF should be created, set inplace=True in the function.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to re-assign the dataframe after you call the `rename` function because `pandas.DataFrame` is a mutable object and therefore it is passed by reference. Have a look on this link on how python objects are passed

https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/

Also, you should use the `inplace` property so that you do not create a new object inside the function. Your code in the rename function will then look like

```
def rename(data):
    data.rename(index=str, columns={'interval_time': 'Timestamp'}, inplace=True)
```

After you call `rename(df)` your DataFrame `df` has its columns renamed.

Comment: actually, using inplace is very often [discouraged] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570984/pandas-is-inplace-true-considered-harmful-or-not). A better solutions btw would just be to not create a new function and just use `data = data.rename(Index=str, columns={'interval_time': 'Timestamp'})`. Anyway this approach and your function are not suitable in pipelines