# pandas python replace/deleting a hyphen in read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am trying to delete all hyphens from a csv data table. Where all values are XYZ-001, XYZ-002, XYZ-003, etc AND I want them to look like XYZ001, XYZ002, XYZ003. I cannot seem to figure out how to use the .replace() feature. Any other ideas??

```
import pandas as pd

dfz = pd.read_csv('control.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dfz[0])
print(dfz['Unnamed: 1'])
dfz['Unnamed: 1'].replace('-','')
```

Comment: `dfz['Unnamed: 1'].str.replace('-','')`

Answer (score 2):

you can also use:

```
df.replace(r'[\W]','',inplace=True,regex=True)
```

if you dont want to use `inplace`  (you can go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570984/pandas-is-inplace-true-considered-harmful-or-not) for pros and cons of `inplace`) you could assign it back like :

```
df = df.replace(r'[\W]','',regex=True)
```

`\W`  finds any character that is not a letter, numeric digit, or the underscore character.

Use this only if you have unknown special characters in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

```
dfz['Unnamed: 1'] = dfz['Unnamed: 1'].str.replace('-','')
```

Remember to assign it back.
Documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)