# .fillna empties the whole column instead of repalcing null values

Tags: python, dataframe, fillna

I have a dataframe with a column named rDREB% which contains missing values, as shown:[count of cells with value of columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQM0u.png). I tried:

```
playersData['rDREB%'] = playersData['rDREB%'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

After executing the code, the whole column will be empty when i check. Isn't the code supposed to replace only null value with 0? i am confused.

[before the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95iT4.png)
[after the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yyayi.png)

P.S. i am also trying to replace other columns with missing values, i.e. ScoreVal, PlayVal, rORB%, OBPM, BPM...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `inplace` means `fillna` returns nothing, which you're assinging to your column. Either remove `inplace`, or don't assign the return value to the column:

`playersData['rDREB%'] = playersData['rDREB%'].fillna(0)`

or

`playersData['rDREB%'].fillna(0, inplace=True)`

The first approach is recommended. See this question for more info: [In pandas, is inplace = True considered harmful, or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570984/in-pandas-is-inplace-true-considered-harmful-or-not)