# Set every second row's index to one new value

Tags: python, pandas

What is a simple and direct way to set the index of every second row of my dataframe to, say, ''?
The method I used to use, `df.loc[1::2, 'index'] = ''` used to work but no longer does. I'm using Pandas version 1.1.0.

It now gives the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()                                                                                  
> lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py(1902)__getitem__()
```

Here's my test setup:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=  pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10), range(10), columns=['foo'])
df.index.name='bar'
```

which gives:

```
       foo
bar          
0    0.818489
1    0.525593
2    0.741739
3    0.250103
4    0.304080
5    0.206198
6    0.982070
7    0.476621
8    0.053609
9    0.726157
```

but the following does nothing:

```
df.loc[1::2].index= ['']*len(df.loc[1::2].index)
```

i.e, the result is still

```
          foo
bar          
0    0.818489
1    0.525593
2    0.741739
3    0.250103
4    0.304080
5    0.206198
6    0.982070
7    0.476621
8    0.053609
9    0.726157
```

**Why does that not work?**

Similarly, this does not work:

```
df.index = df.index.to_numpy()
df.loc[1::2].index= ['']*len(df.loc[1::2].index)
```

**Why not?**

(The effort is motivated by the fact that it looks to me like the index is not just a sequence of integers (like it used to be?)

```
df.index                                                                                                                              
Out[]: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=10, step=1, name='bar')
```

)

This doesn't work, either: `df.loc[1::2,'bar']= ''`.

The following does work (in Pandas 1.0.4 but not 1.1.0), but it involves move the index to a column. Surely that isn't necessary?

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.loc[1::2,'bar']= ''
df.set_index('bar', inplace=True)
```

which gives me what I want, viz:

```
          foo
bar          
0    0.653306
     0.866628
2    0.356007
     0.393833
4    0.770817
     0.131656
6    0.314990
     0.419762
8    0.944348
     0.454487
```

I'm looking for a clean and clear and consise way to carry out this simple modification to matching index values by acting on the index directly.

(n.b. the title of this question isn't perfect. I don't want to use `iloc`; I want to address certain rows' indices all to the same value. So maybe the problem is slightly more general).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way,

```
df = df.set_axis(pd.Index([index if i not in range(1, df.shape[0], 2) else '' 
                           for i, index in enumerate(df.index)], 
                          name=df.index.name))
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
          foo
bar          
0    0.302340
     0.744609
2    0.489255
     0.542356
4    0.072797
     0.810690
6    0.738350
     0.939177
8    0.827072
     0.751731
```

We could also use `DataFrame.Index.values` but [`we need remove RangeIndex`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63220918/set-dataframe-index-values). So the cleanest way is [`DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

```
df = df.rename(index=dict.fromkeys(df.index[1::2],''))
```

Comment: Hey, sorry. I edited my question for better readablility to setting those indices to "" rather than 0. So I edited your answer accordingly! !

Comment: Your second option is a lot prettier to me than the first, but your answer addresses rows by index. That is not what I'm after. I want to set them by value, ideally in one line  / directly in the index.

Comment: @CPBL check now

Comment: Nice. What about just the last answer, using `inplace=True` ?

Comment: you can use it, but you should see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570984/in-pandas-is-inplace-true-considered-harmful-or-not