# Set DataFrame.Index.values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I was answering a [`question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63220461/set-every-second-rows-index-to-one-new-value/63220682#63220682) on StackOverflow, when I encountered the following problem with pandas `1.0.1`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=  pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10), range(10), columns=['foo'])
```

---

```
print(df)
print('\nInitial Index\n')
print(df.index)

print('\nSet DataFrame.index.values\n')
df.index.values[1::2] = 0
print(df.index.values)
print('\nBut df.index does not change\n')
print(df.index)
print(df)
print('\nSetting Index : df.index = df.index.values \n')

df.index = df.index.values
print('\nIndex changed\n')
print(df)
```

---

```
        foo
0  0.213399
1  0.369334
2  0.924745
3  0.778120
4  0.594977
5  0.916565
6  0.603158
7  0.703187
8  0.462739
9  0.728851

Initial Index

RangeIndex(start=0, stop=10, step=1)

Set DataFrame.index.values

[0 0 2 0 4 0 6 0 8 0]

But df.index does not change

RangeIndex(start=0, stop=10, step=1)
        foo
0  0.213399
1  0.369334
2  0.924745
3  0.778120
4  0.594977
5  0.916565
6  0.603158
7  0.703187
8  0.462739
9  0.728851

Setting Index : df.index = df.index.values


Index changed

        foo
0  0.213399
0  0.369334
2  0.924745
0  0.778120
4  0.594977
0  0.916565
6  0.603158
0  0.703187
8  0.462739
0  0.728851
```

it seems that we can change the values ​​attribute from outside the df.index object but this does not change the index.
Is this really thought like this?

shouldn't the `.setter` be removed from the property if this doesn't really change the index?

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.values.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `index` replace we have the `rename` function for it, also it dose not support assignment from its values

```
df.rename(index=dict.fromkeys(df.index[1::2],0))
Out[162]: 
        foo
0  0.166692
0  0.889263
2  0.509025
0  0.688095
4  0.995862
0  0.258366
6  0.080054
0  0.406233
8  0.296096
0  0.680760
```

The problem here is for RangeIndex

> ```
>     if isinstance(data, RangeIndex):
>         return RangeIndex(start=data, copy=copy, dtype=dtype, name=name)
> ```

If we change the range index to other type like below, it will work

```
df.index=[100,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
df.index.values[1::2] = 0 
df
Out[177]: 
          foo
100  0.166692
0    0.889263
1    0.509025
0    0.688095
3    0.995862
0    0.258366
5    0.080054
0    0.406233
7    0.296096
0    0.680760
```

Comment: yes but really the question is why it is allowed to change `df.index.values` ​​if this doesn't really change the index, that is, should `df.index.values ​​[1 :: 2] = 0` return an error?

Comment: @ansev it is happen to range index ~ for other type index should work ~