# Pandas Dataframe : inplace column substitution vs creating new dataframe with transformed column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Whenever I want to transform an existing column of a dataframe, I tend to use `apply/transform` which gives me altogether a new series and it does not modify the existing column in the dataframe.

Suppose the following code performs an operation on a column and returns me a series.

```
new_col1 = df.col1.apply(...)
```

After this I have two ways of substituting the new series in the dataframe

1. modifying the existing `col1`:

   `df.col1 = new_col1`
2. Or creating a new dataframe with the transformed column:

   `df.drop(columns=[col1]).join(new_col1)`

I ask this because whenever I use mutable data structures in python like lists I always try to create new lists using list comprehension and not by in-place substitution.

Is there any benefit of following this style in case of pandas dataframes ? What's more pythonic and which of the above two approaches do you recommend ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are modifying an existing column, the first approach would be faster. Remember that both `drop` and `join` returns a copy of new data, so the second approach can be expensive if you have a big data frame with many columns.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to make changes to the original data frame itself, consider using `inplace=True` attribute in functions like drop/join which by default returns a new copy.

NOTE: Please keep in mind

cons of inplace,

- inplace, contrary to what the name implies, often does not prevent copies from - being created, and (almost) never offers any performance benefits
- inplace does not work with method chaining
- inplace is a common pitfall for beginners, so removing this option will simplify the API

  SOURCE: [In pandas, is inplace = True considered harmful, or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570984/in-pandas-is-inplace-true-considered-harmful-or-not)