# Why can't I access date time data within pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df.reset_index()

DateTime    Demand  Grid1 Load  Grid1 Loss  Grid1 Loss Prophet Daily    
0   01/12/2019 00:00    314.396236  407.67600   21.55210    -3.938760   25.64150    23.9576 -2.50138    
1   01/12/2019 01:00    305.691739  397.96600   20.71190    -4.419430   25.19200    23.9586 -2.48713    
2   01/12/2019 02:00    300.431535  392.90400   20.27340    -4.492290   25.15940    23.9595 -2.46375    


df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format = '%d/%m/%Y/n%H:%H')
```

I am trying to work with the data in the DateTime column but every time I try to access it in any way it returns the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'DateTime'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-80bbba28691a> in <module>
----> 1 df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format = '%d/%m/%Y/n%H:%H')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2925             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2928             if is_integer(indexer):
   2929                 indexer = [indexer]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
-> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2660         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'DateTime'
```

No matter what I try I get the same error, even to try find the data type or to access the column data using

```
df['DateTime']
type(df[DateTime'])
```

Any ideas on what I should try to fix this?

Comment: what does `df.columns` gives you?

Comment: You need to persist your `reset_index`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `error` because you didn't give `inplace` parameter in `reset_index()` method

So due to this `'DateTime'` is consider as `index` instead of `column` in your dataframe

So Write:-

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: `inplace=True` will work but it can be harmful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570984/in-pandas-is-inplace-true-considered-harmful-or-not

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your reset_index is temporarily. You need to persist the changes by assigning your reset to your DataFrame.

```py
...
df = df.reset_index()
```

I would not recommend using `inplace=True` as it's bad practice. Reasons to show that `inplace` is bad see another [SO forum "is in place hamrful"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570984/in-pandas-is-inplace-true-considered-harmful-or-not)

Answer (score 0):

Without resetting index:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
```