# How to iterate over a list of dataframes in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple dataframes, on which I want to run this function which mainly drops unnecessary columns from the dataframe and returns a dataframe:

```
def dropunnamednancols(df):
    """
    Drop any columns staring with unnamed and NaN

    Args:
        df ([dataframe]): dataframe of which columns to be dropped
    """
    
    #first drop nan columns
    df = df.loc[:, df.columns.notnull()]
    #then search for columns with unnamed 
    df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]
    
    return df
```

Now I iterate over the list of dataframes: [df1, df2, df3]

```
dfsublist = [df1, df2, df3]
for index in enumerate(dfsublist):
    dfsublist[index] = dropunnamednancols(dfsublist[index])
```

Whereas the items of *dfsublist* have been changed, the original dataframes *df1*, *df2*, *df3* still retain the unnecessary columns. How could I achieve this?

Comment: If you have small amount of dfs, you can try `df1, df2, df3 = [dropunnamednancols(df) for df in dfsublist]`.

Comment: This is a good tip. I tried list comprehension by dfsublist = [dropunnamednancols(df) for df in dfsublist] which of course did not work out. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to apply a function to multiple dataframes seperately.

The underlaying issue is that in your function you return a new dataframe and replace the stored dataframe in the list with a new own instead of modifying the old orignal one.

If you want to modify the orignal one you have to use the `inplace=True` parameters of the pandas functions. This is possible, but not recommended, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570984/in-pandas-is-inplace-true-considered-harmful-or-not).

Your code could therefore look like this:

```
def dropunnamednancols(df):
    """
    Drop any columns staring with unnamed and NaN

    Args:
        df ([dataframe]): dataframe of which columns to be dropped
    """

    cols = [col for col in df.columns if (col is None) | (col.startswith('Unnamed'))]
    df.drop(cols, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

As example on sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2,3], 'Unnamed':[9,8,7,6]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Unnamed':[9,8,7,6], 'b':[0,1,2,3]})

lst_dfs = [df_1, df_2]

[dropunnamednancols(df) for df in lst_dfs]

# df_1 
# Out[55]: 
#    a
# 0  0
# 1  1
# 2  2
# 3  3
# df_2
# Out[56]: 
#    b
# 0  0
# 1  1
# 2  2
# 3  3
```

Comment: Yes, exactly this is what I wanted to achieve. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Glad I could help. Could you please also mark the answer as 'accepted answer'? This can help future readers with a similar problem. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is probably because your are using enumerate wrong. In your case, you just want the index, so what you should do is:

```
for index in range(len(dfsublist)):
    ...
```

Enumerate returns a tuple of an index and the actual value in your list. So in your code, the loop variable index will actually be asigned:

```
(0, df1) # First iteration
(1, df2) # Second iteration
(2, df3) # Third iteration
```

So either, you use enumerate correctly and unpack the tuple:

```
for index, df in enumerate(dfsublist):
    ...
```

or you get rid of it altogether because you access the values with the index either way.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem here, he wants to change the original dataframes and is just using the list of dataframes to apply the function to them.

Comment: Yes, Andreas is correct. I have tried both solution with enumerate as well. Problem is I want to change the original dataframes and with my approach only a copy is changed.