# pandanic way of inserting df[col].str.extract() results back into original Pandas df immediately after the extraction column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Please refer to the below runnable demo code. It is trying to `sr.str.extract()` the `"a"` column into multiple columns, and insert those columns into the origianl df *immediately* after the `"a"` column.
Please combine steps `[1]` and `[2]` in the below code in a better way.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
     "a" : {1: 'a', 2: 'aa', 3: 'aaa'} ,
     "b" : {1: 'b', 2: 'bb', 3: 'bbb'} ,
     "c" : {1: 'b', 2: 'bb', 3: 'bbb'} ,
})

"""
df==
+----+-----+-----+-----+
|    | a   | b   | c   |
|----+-----+-----+-----|
|  1 | a   | b   | b   |
|  2 | aa  | bb  | bb  |
|  3 | aaa | bbb | bbb |
+----+-----+-----+-----+
"""
# step [1] sr.str.extract
rex = re.compile(r'(?P<firstletter>\w) (?P<secondletter>\w+)', re.X)
cols = df['a'].str.extract(rex)

# step [2] insert extracted columns back into the original df
df['firstletter'], df['secondletter'] = 0, 0
df['firstletter'] = cols['firstletter']
df['secondletter'] = cols['secondletter']
df = df['a firstletter secondletter b c'.split()]

"""
# Or, a more concise step [2], but too hard to glance thru and remember, also prone to mistake:
for col in cols.columns[::-1]:
    df.insert(df.columns.get_loc('a')+1, col, cols[col])
"""

# result:
"""
df==
+----+-----+---------------+----------------+-----+-----+
|    | a   | firstletter   | secondletter   | b   | c   |
|----+-----+---------------+----------------+-----+-----|
|  1 | a   | nan           | nan            | b   | b   |
|  2 | aa  | a             | a              | bb  | bb  |
|  3 | aaa | a             | aa             | bbb | bbb |
+----+-----+---------------+----------------+-----+-----+
"""
```

Comment: I am hoping for a `inplace` operation that looks like: `df.str.extract(col='a', rex, inplace=True)`, which will default insert location after col `'a'`.

Comment: See my edited solutions with 2 options below.

Comment: Note that `inplace` solution is generally considered a bad practice and is of high chance it will be depreciated in future Pandas version.   See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020384/15070697) and also [this article](https://www.dataschool.io/future-of-pandas/#inplace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 possible solutions:

#### Solution 1:

This solution would most resemble your ideal solution while recommend you make some slight (but constructive) change to the naming of the extracted columns.  E.g. instead of `firstletter` and `secondletter`, for the extraction of column `a`, we name it with prefix `a_` as `a_firstletter` and `a_secondletter`.  Then we can use one statement as follows:

```
import re

df = df.assign(**df['a'].str.extract(r'(?P<a_firstletter>\w) (?P<a_secondletter>\w+)', re.X)).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Result:

```
print(df)


     a a_firstletter a_secondletter    b    c
1    a           NaN            NaN    b    b
2   aa             a              a   bb   bb
3  aaa             a             aa  bbb  bbb
```

#### Solution 2:

This solution you can keep on using `firstletter` and `secondletter` as the extracted column names.

You can split the columns into 2 portions by [`.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)  : left portion `df_left` from first column till column `a` and right portion `df_right` from the columns after column `a` till the end.  Then concat the left portion `df_left`, the newly extracted columns `cols`, and right portion `df_right` together along the columns by [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), as follows:

```
df_left = df.iloc[:, 0: df.columns.get_loc('a')+1]
df_right = df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_loc('a')+1:]

df = pd.concat([df_left, cols, df_right], axis=1)
```

Result:

```
print(df)


     a firstletter secondletter    b    c
1    a         NaN          NaN    b    b
2   aa           a            a   bb   bb
3  aaa           a           aa  bbb  bbb
```

Comment: solution 1's syntax is brand new for me, very nice one. I guess the rearranging of columns will always require some extra effort.

Comment: @eliu  Yes,  it's quite tricky to use `df.assign(**df...)` with `**` for unpacking the columns.  Also the column re-arranging here is by `.sort_index()` to sort the 2 extracted columns back together with the column for extraction.

Comment: couldn't really use `.sort_index()` in the real world, the other columns will be rearranged. But the `assign` is really nice

Comment: @eliu   Since you have already maken good use of regex with `Named Capturing Group` so that the extracted columns by `.str.extract()` already carries the column names, you don't need to explicitly code the 2 column names again in the subsequent codes.

Comment: @eliu  If you can't use `.sort_index()` to sort the column names, then probably you have to use my 2nd solution then.  As you require specific locations of the extracted columns, I am afraid this would be the last resort if you don't want to use `.insert()`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need.

```
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({
     "a" : {1: 'a', 2: 'aa', 3: 'aaa'} ,
     "b" : {1: 'b', 2: 'bb', 3: 'bbb'} ,
     "c" : {1: 'b', 2: 'bb', 3: 'bbb'} ,
})

df[['firstletter','secondletter']] = df['a'].str.extract(r"(\w)(\w+)", expand=True)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
     a    b    c firstletter secondletter
1    a    b    b         NaN          NaN
2   aa   bb   bb           a            a
3  aaa  bbb  bbb           a           aa
```

Comment: I does get around the problem of typing 'firstletter' 'secondletter' twice, both in regex and in the code. but it still just a bit short on putting the columns at the desired location.