# If condition in Pandas DataFrame - check if column exists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I am trying to run the following code on a Pandas Database formed by three columns (timestamp, A, B). Occasionally, it could have as well a column named 'C' and I want to check if it exists to do some code:
I would like to create a new column named 'result1' or 'result2', depending on whether 'C' exists or not, and do a division in this column. After that, I would like to drop all columns but the timestamp and the one with the result.

Unfortunately, it is not working and I can't find why (it is not even creating the new columns), could any of you please give me a hand?

```
if 'C' in data.columns:
  data['result1'] = data['C'] / data['A']
  data = data.drop(data.columns.difference(['timestamp', 'result1']), 1, inplace=True)
else:
  data['result2'] = data['B'] / data['A']
  data = data.drop(data.columns.difference(['timestamp', 'result2']), 1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: drop with `inplace=True` returns None.  So, don't assign it back to `data`

Comment: I removed the inplace=True and it works now, thank you!!

Comment: `inplace=True` is not considered a good practice.  It is being gradually deprecated from Pandas.  So avoid using it.  See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020384/15070697) for more information.