# pandas : appending columns to df that is prat of another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have 2 pandas DataFrames:

df1:

| c1 | c2 | x |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 |

and df2:

| c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |

and I want to append the `x` row to `df2` like:

| c1 | c2 | c3 | x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 4 |

I tried to use `join`, but because I don't have a unique index, it didn't work:

```
df1.set_index(['c1', 'c2'], inplace=True)
df2.set_index(['c1', 'c2'], inplace=True,drop=False)
df2=df2.join(df1)
```

df2:

| c1 | c2 | c3 | x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Nan |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | Nan |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | Nan |

Comment: Odd that you get `Nan`. What is the output of `df1[['c1', 'c2']].dtypes` and `df2[['c1', 'c2']].dtypes`?

Comment: at both of the data frames
c1    object
c2    float32
i have checked it on the original data

Comment: thanks for the help
i will try change index

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest way to do what your question asks is this:

```py
df2 = pd.merge(df2, df1, on=['c1', 'c2'])
```

We have done an 'inner' join (the default for pandas.merge()) on columns `c1` and `c2` of dataframes df1 and df2.

Alternatively, this is a way to get the specified result using DataFrame.join() in an approach similar to the one you tried according to your question:

```py
df2 = df2.set_index(['c1', 'c2']).join(df1.set_index(['c1', 'c2'])).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
   c1  c2  c3  x
0   1   1   1  1
1   1   2   1  1
2   2   2   2  4
```

Note that `inplace` has been removed as its use is generally [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020384/18135454), and we now go ahead and allow c1 and c2 columns of df2 to be dropped by set_index() and use reset_index() later to restore them.

Comment: @Avichai Edri Did this answer your question? Do you need any additional help?