# How to remove dataframe rows with empty objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame with the below structure

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 13 entries, 0 to 12
Data columns (total 8 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------        --------------  ----- 
 0   id            13 non-null     object
 1   case_num      13 non-null     int64 
 2   pn_num        13 non-null     int64 
 3   feature_num   13 non-null     int64 
 4   annotation    13 non-null     object
 5   location      13 non-null     object
 6   feature_text  13 non-null     object
 7   pn_history    13 non-null     object
```

Inside this data frame the annotation and location columns sometimes contain empty values
as below:

[image: dataframe]

I want to remove the rows which are empty and tried to use the below commands but none of this is working.

```
df[df['annotation'].str.len() > 0]
```

```
df[df['annotation'].map(lambda d: len(d)) > 0]
```

output of command

```
print(df.head(15).to_dict())
```

is as below

```
{'id': {0: '00016_000', 1: '00016_001', 2: '00016_002', 3: '00016_003', 4: '00016_004', 5: '00016_005', 6: '00016_006', 7: '00016_007', 8: '00016_008', 9: '00016_009', 10: '00016_010', 11: '00016_011', 12: '00016_012'}, 'case_num': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0}, 'pn_num': {0: 16, 1: 16, 2: 16, 3: 16, 4: 16, 5: 16, 6: 16, 7: 16, 8: 16, 9: 16, 10: 16, 11: 16, 12: 16}, 'feature_num': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12}, 'annotation': {0: "['dad with recent heart attcak']", 1: '[\'mom with "thyroid disease\']', 2: "['chest pressure']", 3: "['intermittent episodes', 'episode']", 4: "['felt as if he were going to pass out']", 5: '[]', 6: "['adderall', 'adderrall', 'adderrall']", 7: '[]', 8: '[]', 9: "['palpitations', 'heart beating/pounding']", 10: "['3-4 months of']", 11: "['17yo']", 12: "['M']"}, 'location': {0: "['696 724']", 1: "['668 693']", 2: "['203 217']", 3: "['70 91', '176 183']", 4: "['222 258']", 5: '[]', 6: "['321 329', '404 413', '652 661']", 7: '[]', 8: '[]', 9: "['26 38', '96 118']", 10: "['56 69']", 11: "['5 9']", 12: "['10 11']"}, 'feature_text': {0: 'Family-history-of-MI-OR-Family-history-of-myocardial-infarction', 1: 'Family-history-of-thyroid-disorder', 2: 'Chest-pressure', 3: 'Intermittent-symptoms', 4: 'Lightheaded', 5: 'No-hair-changes-OR-no-nail-changes-OR-no-temperature-intolerance', 6: 'Adderall-use', 7: 'Shortness-of-breath', 8: 'Caffeine-use', 9: 'heart-pounding-OR-heart-racing', 10: 'Few-months-duration', 11: '17-year', 12: 'Male'}, 'pn_history': {0: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms', 1: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms', 2: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms', 3: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms', 4: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms', 5: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms', 6: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms', 7: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms', 8: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms', 9: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms', 10: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms', 11: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms', 12: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms'}}
```

kindly advise how can I fix this.

Comment: you possibly don't have a list object, but a string of a list. can you `print(df.head(15).to_dict())` post the result in your question.

Comment: have updated the question, please advise.

Comment: You have strings instead of list in those columns. Maybe just do `df[df['annotation'] != '[]']`. Definitely not ideal but could  work.

Comment: @Psidom, yes your suggestion worked!!

Comment: `df[df["annotation"].map(pd.eval).str.len() > 1]` will work as you need to correctly parse the object first. Or just deal with the object as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do what your question asks based on an `annotation` column which contains values that look like lists but are actually strings:

```py
df = df[df.annotation.apply(eval).str.len() > 0]
```

Column `annotation` from sample input (taken from `df.head(15)` in your question):

```
                                    annotation
0             ['dad with recent heart attcak']
1                ['mom with "thyroid disease']
2                           ['chest pressure']
3         ['intermittent episodes', 'episode']
4     ['felt as if he were going to pass out']
5                                           []
6       ['adderall', 'adderrall', 'adderrall']
7                                           []
8                                           []
9   ['palpitations', 'heart beating/pounding']
10                           ['3-4 months of']
11                                    ['17yo']
12                                       ['M']
```

Column `annotation` of result:

```
                                    annotation
0             ['dad with recent heart attcak']
1                ['mom with "thyroid disease']
2                           ['chest pressure']
3         ['intermittent episodes', 'episode']
4     ['felt as if he were going to pass out']
6       ['adderall', 'adderrall', 'adderrall']
9   ['palpitations', 'heart beating/pounding']
10                           ['3-4 months of']
11                                    ['17yo']
12                                       ['M']
```

Full test code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: '00016_000', 1: '00016_001', 2: '00016_002', 3: '00016_003', 4: '00016_004', 5: '00016_005', 6: '00016_006', 7: '00016_007', 8: '00016_008', 9: '00016_009', 10: '00016_010', 11: '00016_011', 12: '00016_012'}, 'case_num': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0}, 'pn_num': {0: 16, 1: 16, 2: 16, 3: 16, 4: 16, 5: 16, 6: 16, 7: 16, 8: 16, 9: 16, 10: 16, 11: 16, 12: 16}, 'feature_num': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12}, 'annotation': {0: "['dad with recent heart attcak']", 1: '[\'mom with "thyroid disease\']', 2: "['chest pressure']", 3: "['intermittent episodes', 'episode']", 4: "['felt as if he were going to pass out']", 5: '[]', 6: "['adderall', 'adderrall', 'adderrall']", 7: '[]', 8: '[]', 9: "['palpitations', 'heart beating/pounding']", 10: "['3-4 months of']", 11: "['17yo']", 12: "['M']"}, 'location': {0: "['696 724']", 1: "['668 693']", 2: "['203 217']", 3: "['70 91', '176 183']", 4: "['222 258']", 5: '[]', 6: "['321 329', '404 413', '652 661']", 7: '[]', 8: '[]', 9: "['26 38', '96 118']", 10: "['56 69']", 11: "['5 9']", 12: "['10 11']"}, 'feature_text': {0: 'Family-history-of-MI-OR-Family-history-of-myocardial-infarction', 1: 'Family-history-of-thyroid-disorder', 2: 'Chest-pressure', 3: 'Intermittent-symptoms', 4: 'Lightheaded', 5: 'No-hair-changes-OR-no-nail-changes-OR-no-temperature-intolerance', 6: 'Adderall-use', 7: 'Shortness-of-breath', 8: 'Caffeine-use', 9: 'heart-pounding-OR-heart-racing', 10: 'Few-months-duration', 11: '17-year', 12: 'Male'}, 'pn_history': {0: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms', 1: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms', 2: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms', 3: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms', 4: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms', 5: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms', 6: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms', 7: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms', 8: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms', 9: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms', 10: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms', 11: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms', 12: 'HPI: 17yo M presents with palpitations. Patient reports 3-4 months of intermittent episodes of "heart beating/pounding out of my chest." 2 days ago during a soccer game had an episode, but this time had chest pressure and felt as if he were going to pass out (did not lose conciousness). Of note patient endorses abusing adderall, primarily to study (1-3 times per week). Before recent soccer game, took adderrall night before and morning of game. Denies shortness of breath, diaphoresis, fevers, chills, headache, fatigue, changes in sleep, changes in vision/hearing, abdominal paun, changes in bowel or urinary habits. \r\nPMHx: none\r\nRx: uses friends adderrall\r\nFHx: mom with "thyroid disease," dad with recent heart attcak\r\nAll: none\r\nImmunizations: up to date\r\nSHx: Freshmen in college. Endorses 3-4 drinks 3 nights / week (on weekends), denies tabacco, endorses trying marijuana. Sexually active with girlfriend x 1 year, uses condoms'}})

print(df.annotation.to_frame())
df = df[df.annotation.apply(eval).str.len() > 0]
print(df.annotation.to_frame())
```

Comment: sorry, your suggestion didn't work. If you look closely at the annotation data in my question it is not exactly list, its rather something like ['a b', 'c d', 'e f' ].

Comment: I see now that the `annotation` column as shown in the output of `df.head(15)` contains elements which look like list initializers when printed but are of type `str`, not `list`. Please see my updated answer which seems to work using your `df.head(15)` data as the test case.

Comment: @tanmay Do you need additional help with your question?

Answer (score 2):

Use df.replace() to replace `empty object` with `NaN data` and drop rows with empty strings from a Pandas dataframe

[image: data set]

```
#Convert NaN values to empty string.
nan_value = float("NaN")
df. replace("", nan_value, inplace=True)
df. dropna(subset = ["column2"], inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: recommend not using `inplace=True` as it can lead to bad unintended results. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570984/in-pandas-is-inplace-true-considered-harmful-or-not)

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a fantastic function for dropping all rows which contain any `NA` values, and that is the [`DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) function:

```py
df = df.dropna()
```

If you only want to drop those rows which have *all* NA values, then you can use the keyword argument `how='all'`:

```py
df = df.dropna(how='all')
```

Comment: sorry, none of the above commands worked, I am not getting any error on running these commands but the rows with empty values for the columns that I mentioned still persist in the data frame, they are not deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In your case do

```
df[df['annotation'].ne('[]')]
```

Comment: your suggestion didn't removed the rows, instead I used df=df[df['annotation'] != '[]'] which worked.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what @BENY has suggested will work, assuming you assign the result to `df` like this: `df = df[df['annotation'].ne('[]')]`.