# Python Pandas data frame cell value does not update after using clip

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I experienced some quite unexpected behavior when using the clip function of pandas.

So, here is a reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
df_init = pd.DataFrame({'W': [-1.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3, 0.5, 1.0]})
df_init['W_EX'] = df_init['W'] + 0.1
df_init['W_EX'].clip(upper=1.0, inplace=True)
df_init.loc[df_init['W']==-1.0, 'W_EX'] = -1.0
df_init
```

The output is, as one would expect:

```
Out[2]: 
     W  W_EX
0 -1.0  -1.0
1  0.0   0.1
2  0.0   0.1
3  0.3   0.4
4  0.5   0.6
5  1.0   1.0
```

However, when I inspect a specific value:

```
df_init.loc[df_init['W']==-1.0, 'W_EX']
```

I see the following output:

```
Out[3]: 
0   -0.9
Name: W_EX, dtype: float64
```

Although I used `.loc` to overwrite the first value on the column, and although when printing the data frame I can see the new value, when I use `.loc` with a row slice, I see the value, which I had before using `.clip`.

Now it gets more complicated. If I inspect the series on the new column, I can see the value has been indeed updated:

```
df_init.loc[df_init['W']==-1.0, ['W_EX']]

Out[4]: 
   W_EX
0  -1.0
```

And lastly, like in Schrödinger's cat experiment, if I now go back and look a the column values, after having inspected the column series, I can now actually see, that the value's indeed the one I would have expected in the first place (as in `Out[3]:`):

```
df_init.loc[df_init['W']==-1.0, 'W_EX']

Out[5]: 
0   -1.0
Name: W_EX, dtype: float64
```

If I skip the `.clip` call, all is fine. Would someone more knowledgeable than myself, please explain me what is going here?

Comment: So after a bit of digging, I managed to narrow it down to this - it has something to do with doing the .clip operation inplace. If I do this, none of the unexpected behavior occurs:

Comment: There's some weirdsness going on with `inplace=True`. It looks like it's not performing assignment the way you expect. It may be better to default to explicit assignment so it's clearer what's happening. `df_init['W_EX'] = df_init['W_EX'].clip(upper=1.0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be better to default to explicit assignment so that it's clearer what's happening. `inplace=True` performed on this slice of the dataframe doesn't appear to be assigning as expected, consistently.

There's some debate on whether the flag should stick around *at all*. [In pandas, is inplace = True considered harmful, or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570984/in-pandas-is-inplace-true-considered-harmful-or-not)

```py
df_init['W_EX'] = df_init['W_EX'].clip(upper=1.0)
```

Comment: Hey Joe, thank you very much for the pointer to the discussion. Honestly, I have already come around to accepting, that `inplace=True` is harmful when deployed on slices (rows or columns alike). I still find it useful for stuff like `df.columns.rename({...}, inplace=True)` though. One thing I can't wrap my head around is this - why do the cell values on the data frame change after merely observing the column series with `df_init.loc[df_init['W']==-1.0, ['W_EX']]` ?