# Dropping rows based on a string in a table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pdf, tabula

Code to drop rows based on a partial string is not working.

Very simple code, and it runs fine but doesn't drop the rows I want.

The original table in the pdf looks like this:

| Chemical | Value | Unit | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fluoride | 0.23 | ug/L | Lab |
| Mercury | 0.15 | ug/L | Lab |
| Sum of Long Chained Polymers | 0.33 |  |  |
| Partialsum of Short Chained Polymers | 0.40 |  |  |

What I did:

```
import csv 
import tabula

dfs = tabula.read _pdf("Test.pdf", pages= 'all')
file = "Test.pdf"
tables = tabula.read_pdf(file, pages=2, stream=True, multiple_tables=True)

table1 = tables[1]
table1.drop('Unit', axis=1, inplace=True) 
table1.drop('Type', axis=1, inplace=True)
discard = ['sum','Sum']
table1[~table1.Chemical.str.contains('|'.join(discard))]
print(table1)
table1.to_csv('test.csv')
```

The results are that it drops the 2 columns I don't want, so that's fine. But it did not delete the rows with the words "sum" or "Sum" in them.  Any insights?

Comment: Please post a working example - We don't have your pdf, but really, that part is irrelevant. You could initialize `table1` to the example values. And then fix the invalid reference to `.Parameter`.

Comment: I fixed the "Parameter" - was supposed to be "Chemical".  

I am not sure how to "post a working example", so maybe I am in over my head here.  If it was working, I wouldn't be asking, so maybe I am misunderstanding. The above code runs, but doesn't delete the rows containing "sum" in the Chemical column.

Comment: Yeah, narrowing down examples can be challenging but helps the rest of us. In my answer I included a note on how I generated the script. Its a good skill to develop as a python developer. Whenever I hit a roadblock, I fire up the python shell or write one-off test scripts to focus on just problem area.

Comment: See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Also see: [In pandas, is inplace = True considered harmful, or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020384/11865956)

Answer (score 0):

You are close. You did drop the rows, but you didn't save the result.

```
import pandas as pd

example = {'Chemical': ['Fluoride', 'Mercury', 'Sum of Long Chained Polymers',
                'Partialsum of Short Chained Polymers'], 
            'Value': [0.23, 0.15, 0.33, 0.4], 
            'Unit': ['ug/L', 'ug/L', '', ''], 
            'Type': ['Lab', 'Lab', '', '']}

table1 = pd.DataFrame(example)
table1.drop('Unit', axis=1, inplace=True)
table1.drop('Type', axis=1, inplace=True)
discard = ['sum','Sum']
table1 = table1[~table1.Chemical.str.contains('|'.join(discard))]
print(table1)
```

Comment: To get this example, I copied your table and used `table1 = pd.read_clipboard()`. But that's still not something others can replicate, so I used `table1.to_dict()` to write a dictionary. Pasting that into a test.py file, I had the data without the pdf part. Its more focused and others can run it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.Series.str.contains` with the argument `case=False` to ignore case:

Also, it's not law, but often considered poor practice to use `inplace=True`... because in part it leads to confusions like the one you're experiencing.

Given `df`:

```
                               Chemical  Value  Unit  Type
0                              Fluoride   0.23  ug/L   Lab
1                               Mercury   0.15  ug/L   Lab
2          Sum of Long Chained Polymers   0.33   NaN   NaN
3  Partialsum of Short Chained Polymers   0.40   NaN   NaN
```

Doing:

```
df = (df.drop(['Unit', 'Type'], axis=1)
        .loc[~df.Chemical.str.contains('sum', case=False)])
```

Output:

```
   Chemical  Value
0  Fluoride   0.23
1   Mercury   0.15
```