# Why is it not possible to iterate over pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, iteration

Let there be several similar dataframes that an operation is to be performed on, e.g. dropping or renaming columns. One may want to do it in a loop:

```py
this = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['Hello World']})
that = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['Hello Gurl']})

for df in [this, that]:
    df = df.rename(columns={'text': 'content'})
```

No exception is raised, however, the dataframes remain unchanged. Why is that and how can I iterate over dataframes without having to type the same line of code dozens of times?

On other hand, operations like creating new columns do work:

```py
for df in [this, that]:
    df['content'] = df.text
```

Comment: inside your loop in the first case, you change what the name `df` references not the reference as you do in the second case

Answer (score 0):

Call `.rename()` with `inplace=True` to have it modify the DF itself.

```
this = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['Hello World']})
that = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['Hello Gurl']})

for df in [this, that]:
    df.rename(columns={'text': 'content'}, inplace=True)
```

As to "why it's not modified", it's similar to, say,

```
this = ("foo",)
that = ("bar",)

for x in (this, that):
    x = x + ("blarp",)
```

not assigning `("foo", "blarp")` and `("bar", "blarp")` back to `this` and `that`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `df.rename` returns a new data frame. This is also the case with a lot of pandas's functions. Add `inplace=true`:

```py
for df in [this, that]:
    df.rename(columns={'text': 'content'}, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename your columns inplace, you can use `rename` method with `inplace=True` as parameter but you can also rename directly the `Index` because it's not a method that returns a copy:

```
d = {'text': 'content'}

for df in [this, that]:
    df.columns = [d.get(col, col) for col in df.columns]
```

Output:

```
>>> this
       content
0  Hello World

>>> that
      content
0  Hello Gurl
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have mentioned, `rename` returns a copy, and the original DataFrame is not changed. And since you are creating a temporarily list on the fly, there is no way to get the updated results back once the loop is done.

#### [`inplace=True` is harmful in my opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020384/4909087).

So don't use it. Some answers have suggested using a list/dict, a small change to your code is in order:

```
dfs = [this, that]
for i in range(len(dfs)):
    dfs[i] = dfs[i].rename(...) # do something with dfs[i] and assign it back
# unpack the result
this, that = dfs
```

this works because the result of the `rename` operation is assigned back to the list that you have a reference to.