# Variable assignment for dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

What explains the difference in time to process column renaming in a Python dataframe?  At first, I used the code df=df.rename(columns = {'colold':'colnew'}).  This proved to be inefficient.  I modified the code and used df.rename(columns = {'colold':'colnew'}) which reduced the processing time.  While it seems obvious that the later approach would take less time as it reduces a step, why is this the case.  In the following code, the difference between both approaches is about 30 seconds.

```
 import time
   import numpy as np
   import random
   import pandas as pd


   def fun_user_id(start, end, step):
    num = np.linspace(start, end,(end-start)
                      *int(1/step)+1).tolist()
    return [round(i, 0) for i in num]

   def fun_rand_num():
    return list(map(lambda x: random.randint(300,800), range(1, 20000001)))

   if __name__=='__main__':
    userid=fun_user_id(1,20000001,.5)
    var1=fun_rand_num()
    var2=fun_rand_num()
    var3=fun_rand_num()
    var4=fun_rand_num()
    var5=fun_rand_num()
    var6=fun_rand_num()
    var7=fun_rand_num()
    var8=fun_rand_num()
    var9=fun_rand_num()
    var10=fun_rand_num()
    var1a=fun_rand_num()
    var2a=fun_rand_num()
    var3a=fun_rand_num()
    var4a=fun_rand_num()
    var5a=fun_rand_num()
    var6a=fun_rand_num()
    var7a=fun_rand_num()
    var8a=fun_rand_num()
    var9a=fun_rand_num()
    var10a=fun_rand_num()
    
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(userid,var1, var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8,var9,var10,var1a,var2a,var3a,var4a,var5a,var6a,var7a,var8a,var9a,var10a)),
                   columns =['userid','var1', 'var2','var3','var4','var5',
                             'var6', 'var7','var8','var9','var10',
                             'var1a', 'var2a','var3a','var4a','var5a',
                             'var6a', 'var7a','var8a','var9a','var10a'])

    start1 = time.time()
   
    df=df.rename(columns = {'var1':'VAR1'})
    df=df.rename(columns = {'var2':'VAR2'})
    df=df.rename(columns = {'var3':'VAR3'})
    df=df.rename(columns = {'var4':'VAR4'})
    df=df.rename(columns = {'var5':'VAR5'})
    df=df.rename(columns = {'var1a':'VAR1a'})
    df=df.rename(columns = {'var2a':'VAR2a'})
    df=df.rename(columns = {'var3a':'VAR3a'})
    df=df.rename(columns = {'var4a':'VAR4a'})
    df=df.rename(columns = {'var5a':'VAR5a'})
    end1= time.time()
    print(f"Elapsed time rename df reassigned : {end1 - start1:.2f} seconds")

    start2 = time.time()
    df.rename(columns = {'var6':'VAR6'})
    df.rename(columns = {'var7':'VAR7'})
    df.rename(columns = {'var8':'VAR8'})
    df.rename(columns = {'var9':'VAR9'})
    df.rename(columns = {'var10':'VAR10'})
    df.rename(columns = {'var6a':'VAR6a'})
    df.rename(columns = {'var7a':'VAR7a'})
    df.rename(columns = {'var8a':'VAR8a'})
    df.rename(columns = {'var9a':'VAR9a'})
    df.rename(columns = {'var10a':'VAR10a'})

    end2= time.time()
    print(f"Elapsed time rename df not reassigned : {end2 - start2:.2f} seconds")

    print(f"Time Difference : {(end2 - start2)-(end1 - start1):.2f} seconds")
```

Comment: Have you checked what `df` looks like after your second approach?

Answer (score 0):

df.rename() without reassignment doesn't change the column name, You need to use df.rename(columns={'col':'new_col'}, inplace=True) and test the time taken

Comment: additionally, you may read about inplace parameter and argument against using it or not. There are certain posts one of which im linking here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570984/in-pandas-is-inplace-true-considered-harmful-or-not