# Any situation where I would want to use inplace=True vs df=df?

Tags: python, pandas, in-place

A bit confused about inplace argument. In particular if there is any benefit in using it vs the standard approach of just writing df=df to clarify that we change the dataframe we are working with?

Comment: Probably not. Maybe it doesn't harm and you like how the code reads, but check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/understanding-inplace-true-in-pandas and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570984/in-pandas-is-inplace-true-considered-harmful-or-not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a big difference, if several names are pointing to the same object. `df = df.do_something()` does **not** work in place, it just reassigns the copy to the same name.

Here is an example demonstrating the difference.

Reassigning `df`, `df2` is unchanged, it still points to the original object and `df` to the new output.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, float('nan'), 3]})
df2 = df

df = df.dropna()
print(df2)

   col1
0   1.0
1   NaN
2   3.0
```

With `inplace=True` the object is modified in place.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, float('nan'), 3]})
df2 = df

df.dropna(inplace=True)
print(df2)

   col1
0   1.0
2   3.0
```

In real life, I don't really see a use case to keep multiple reference to the same object. Given pandas complexity, it's sometimes hard to keep track of views and copies. I would recommend to avoid `inplace=True`. In fact, there is a [discussion to remove this parameter for most functions](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529).

Comment: Interesting, had no idea that inplace can actually create such a difference. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

inplace=True, write or edit the original data in RAM, and no need to return

inplace=False, create a new copy data in RAM, and edit it, and then return it

Comment: The OP seems to know that. The actual question is whether to use `inplace=True` vs. an explicit assignation ("the standard approach of just writing df=df")