# why inplace=True behave differently when apply to a single column view than apply to a multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been heavily using scipy and numpy form many years. There performance is very important so we normally do not copy data whenever possible.
I also use pandas superficially for more than 10 years. I usually thought inplace=True means no-copy on data during operation.

However, recently I encountered some [strange problem on mask(inplace=True)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77552859/inplace-mask-does-not-work-is-this-expected-or-it-is-a-bug), let me doubt I might be wrong.
I also came across several discussing:

[In pandas, is inplace = True considered harmful, or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570984/in-pandas-is-inplace-true-considered-harmful-or-not)

[Understanding inplace=True in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/understanding-inplace-true-in-pandas) (this post almost just repeat the points and claims from the previous post)

In there people argue the inplace has no value in most cases, because it will copy-on-write by default.

However, I think the argument is wrong (at least for pandas 2.x) according to document: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/copy_on_write.html

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.options.mode.copy_on_write)
# False
```

apparently the CoW is not on by default, so I really doubt the claim: it always copy behind the scene. This also against my experience, when I use inplace=True, it definitely reduce my memory usage in most cases. I can verify this with memory_profiler

Here is my test in ipython, the peak memory is not important here, increment means how much memory was used by that line:

```
%load_ext memory_profiler
import numpy as np
df_big = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(int(1e7),3), columns=["A", "B", "C"])
str_source = ["foofoofoo", "barbarbar", "hello world"]
df_big['STR'] = np.random.choice(str_source, df_big.shape[0])

display(df_big.memory_usage().sum()/1024**2) # show 305MB
df_big2 = df_big.copy()

%%memit
df_big2.replace("barbarbar", "rabrabrab", inplace=True)
# peak memory: 1778.38 MiB, increment: 76.25 MiB
%%memit
df_big3 = df_big.replace("barbarbar", "rabrabrab", inplace=False)
# peak memory: 2007.23 MiB, increment: 305.16 MiB

%%memit
df_big2.loc[:, "STR"].replace("foofoofoo", "oofoofoof", inplace=True)
# peak memory: 1778.55 MiB, increment: 76.38 MiB
%%memit
df_big2.loc[:, "STR"] = df_big2.loc[:, "STR"].replace("oofoofoof", "foofoofoo", inplace=False)
# peak memory: 1854.80 MiB, increment: 152.50 MiB
```

**It is very clear the replace(inplace=True) reduce memory usage a lot.** 76MB vs 305MB if replace the entire dataframe or 76MB vs 152MB if replace only 1 column.
**So the inplace do have big value for us if one often has GB size dataframe like me.**

from here https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529 its author also admitted actually more functions benefit from inplace if you look at the list under:

> Should be able to not copy memory (under discussion on what to do)

The list is far longer than the list surely has no benefit.

So my question here is which functions in what condition actually CoW even when inplace=True?

Is there any official source about this? Or is there a way to tell if a function actually create copy behind the scene or not?

Or maybe this has something to do with the .loc[] not the inplace argument?

I though the .loc[] always return view without copy https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

however, it seems not the case. if I do df.loc[:, 'A'].mask(df.loc[:, 'A']<0, inplace=True), it actually change the df.

if I do df.loc[:, ['A', 'B']].mask(df.loc[:, 'A']<0, inplace=True), though it does not raise any error about modify a copy of data.
It does not modify the df at all, which indicate it actually modified a copy of the view.

Samething happens to .where(), .replace(), and even more maybe

let's use the same example, simple change "STR" to ["STR"], so now we return a sub dataframe instead of a Series:

```
%%memit
df_big2.loc[:, ["STR"]].replace("foofoofoo", "oofoof123", inplace=True)
# peak memory: 3325.38 MiB, increment: 152.50 MiB
```

now, we can tell from the memory usage, it indeed created a copy in this case. But surprisingly it does not raise the SettingWithCopyWarning, which make me doubt it is expected behaviour.

So the behaviour is very strange right here, is there a stable rule about in which cases the .loc[] make a copy?

The increased memory size 76.3MB, which is the STR column size, indicates that, the underline Series still gets copied before modification. But it is strange that .loc[:, ["STR"]] need to copy it twice, Even more strange the .loc[:, "STR"].replace(inplace=False), also need to copy it twice too. Isn't python has a very mature way to handle this already? like the tuple in a list, double copy rarely happens there. To this point I feel either there is some bug or the pandas use the memory in a very very inefficient way.

Comment: have you seen this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/understanding-inplace-true-in-pandas#:~:text=The%20'inplace%3DTrue'%20argument,to%20make%20changes%20permanent%20eg.&text=pandas%20shows%20the%20dataframe%20with,the%20original%20dataframe%20'df'.&text=If%20you%20don't%20use,basically%20get%20back%20a%20copy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding inplace=True in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/understanding-inplace-true-in-pandas)

Comment: I apparently referred to that post myself already, and I also stated why it does not answer my question. @D.L I also stated why I think their claims are actually wrong

Comment: and more, I stated at the end part, I am not sure it is the problem of inplace or rather a problem of .loc[], this is more about the expected behavior of interaction between .loc[] and the inplace=True together.