# Using the DataFrame.set_index() method

Tags: python, pandas

Good morning,

I have a some error and time data in two columns:

```
edf = pd.DataFrame({'error':error, 'time':time})
```

Which gives:

```
            error    time
0     0.000000e+00 -10.000
1     4.219215e-28  -9.995
2     8.870728e-28  -9.990
3     1.398745e-27  -9.985
4     1.960445e-27  -9.980
5     2.575915e-27  -9.975
6     3.249142e-27  -9.970
7     3.984379e-27  -9.965
8     4.786157e-27  -9.960
9     5.659303e-27  -9.955
10    6.608959e-27  -9.950
```

According to documentation, I can use `edf.set_index('time', drop=True)` in order to set the time column as my index, and drop it from the its previous place in the data frame (I believe it drops by default). However, this does absolutely nothing. In fact, I was so confused, that I decided to copy and paste the code example straight from documentation, and indeed it does not work either.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 4, 7, 10],
                   'year': [2012, 2014, 2013, 2014],
                   'sale': [55, 40, 84, 31]})
```

Which gives,

```
   month  year  sale
0      1  2012    55
1      4  2014    40
2      7  2013    84
3     10  2014    31
```

After which, `df.set_index('month')` also gives:

```
   month  year  sale
0      1  2012    55
1      4  2014    40
2      7  2013    84
3     10  2014    31
```

Instead of what documentation advertises:

```
       year  sale
month
1      2012    55
4      2014    40
7      2013    84
10     2014    31
```

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set_index` returns the new dataframe by default. So use:

```
# recommended
edf.set_index('time', drop=True, inplace=True)
```

or

```
edf = edf.set_index('time', drop=True)
```

Comment: Personally, I always prefer to be explicit and never use `inplace` (i.e. I would always use the second method).  In fact, `inplace` is expected to be deprecated. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529

Comment: The linked GitHub issue is still discussion and not final. In my experience, `inplace=True` does sometimes save  a lot of memory.

Comment: It is certainly debatable, which is why I highlighted the difference of opinion.  I don't believe there would be any difference in memory usage. Do you have any references where I could learn more about that?  Here is some more SO discussion on inplace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570984/pandas-is-inplace-true-considered-harmful-or-not

Comment: @Alexander I don't have any reference. That came purely from my experience. However, from your links, [inplace is good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34320137/guidelines-on-using-pandas-inplace-keyword-argument/34326313#34326313) does show the difference in memory usage.

Comment: And the [in-place is bad!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22533110/8425408) link shows they that example may not hold in practice. I think we can agree that it is a point of disagreement as to best practice.

Comment: The bad link only shows run time stats, not memory usage!

Comment: "Often they are actually the same operation that works on a copy" implies higher memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

Most dataframe operations don't modify the original dataframe by default. Instead, they return a new dataframe as a result.

You could assign that result to a new variable, or to the same one:

```
df = df.set_index('month')
```

Or you could pass a parameter to the function to tell it to modify the original dataframe in place:

```
df.set_index('month', inplace=True)
```

This tripped me up a lot when I started working with Pandas.